# Intento traducir mi codigo de sql a Algebra Relacional

Tags: sql

Buenas noches estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio y se me pide convertir mis consultas de sql en algebra relacional pero mi ultima consulta no consigo sacarla y necesito ayuda.

Estoy realizando consultas sobre mis dos tablas Empleados y Telefonos, y a la hora de hacer la consulta de los telefonos de las personas que ocupan el despacho 8, no consigo traducir del todo esa consulta a Algebra relacional.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Empleados,Telefono cascade;
CREATE TABLE Empleados (
IdEmpleado SMALLINT CONSTRAINT PK_Empleados PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
nombre CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Despacho SMALLINT NOT NULL,
horario CHAR(10) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Telefono (
IdEmpleado SMALLINT CONSTRAINT FK_TelefonoEmpleado REFERENCES empleados,
Telefono NUMERIC(9)
);

insert into Empleados values
(1,DATE '09-07-2002','Sofia',6,'Mañana'),
(2,DATE '17-02-2002','Rodrigo',6,'Tarde'),
(3,DATE '18-06-2001','Celia',8,'Mañana'),
(4,DATE '20-05-2000','Victor',8,'Tarde'),
(5,DATE '12-09-1999','Pedro',8,'Tarde');

insert into Telefono values
(1,627382321),(2,627234567),(3,627345890),(4,627385461),(5,622348232);

--Teléfono de las personas que ocupan el despacho 8
SELECT nombre, telefono
FROM telefono
INNER JOIN empleados
ON telefono.IdEmpleado = empleados.IdEmpleado
AND despacho = 8;
```

```
Empleados = {IdEmpleado fecha_nacimiento nombre Despacho horario
1 09-07-2002 Sofia 6 Manana 
2 17-02-2002 Rodrigo 6 Tarde
3 18-06-2001 Celia 8 Manana
4 20-05-2000 Victor 8 Tarde
5 12-09-1999 Pedro 8 Tarde
}
Telefono = {IdEmpleado Telefono
1 627382321
2 627234567
3 627345890
4 627385461
5 622348232
}

-- Teléfono de las personas que ocupan el despacho 8
(π nombre (Empleados) join π Telefono (Telefono)) join σ IdEmpleado(Telefono) = IdEmpleado(Empleados)
```

Answer (score 0):

Datos de ejemplo de la pregunta:

```
Empleados = {
IdEmpleado, Nombre, Despacho

1, 'Sofia', 6
2, 'Rodrigo', 6 
3, 'Celia', 8 
4, 'Victor', 8
5, 'Pedro', 8 
}

Telefono = {
IdEmpleado, Telefono

1, 627382321
2, 627234567
3, 627345890
4, 627385461
5, 622348232
}
```

**Una opción podría ser:**

```
π Nombre, Telefono 
( Telefono JOIN Telefono.IdEmpleado = Empleados.IdEmpleado AND Despacho = 8 Empleados )

ó

π Nombre, Telefono 
( Telefono ⨝ Telefono.IdEmpleado = Empleados.IdEmpleado ∧ Despacho = 8 Empleados )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]